# Combining two raster layers in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, layers, merge, combine

I am trying to create a raster map with cells with the value 0 (outside study area), and the other cells with value 1 (the study area)

I have two input layers for this (the image below)
How can I make the two separate layers below into one layer with:

- value 0 (blue) = outside the study area
- value 1 (black) = study area

I tried tools such as the mosaic tools. However, the value now for both the layers below is 1, so I think this is the reason it did not combine.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options.  Some easy ones are...
Option 1: [Reclassify](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/reclassify.htm).  Reclassify your study area raster such that 1 = 1 and NoData = 0.  You can [use environment settings](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/environment-settings/output-extent.htm) to ensure that the output is the same extent as the not-study-area raster.
Option 2: [Con](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/con-.htm).  Use the Con function such that if study area = 1 take the value from study area else take the value from not study area.

Comment: Thank you. The reclassify is indeed nice option. However, when i try to assign a new value to the NODATA it does not allow me to make this 0. It changes automatically back to 'NODATA'. Is it an issue that my two input layers have both a value of 1?

Comment: ah it did work thank you, i did not press enter

Comment: Great, if you would accept the answer I would appreciate it.